# Sorting a table values based on index and non-indexed columns using python

Tags: python, pandas

How can I sort values in a dataframe based on an index and non-indexed columns?

Dataframe:

```
ID  Colour  A   B   C
45356   Green   1   34  4
34455   Yellow  23  0   1
53443   Brown   3   4   3
45555   Green   5   5   2
```

Table has two index columns (ID and Colour). I will like to sort the table based on ID(ascending), A (Descending) and C (ascending).

Required output is :

```
ID  Colour  A   B   C
34455   Yellow  23  0   1
45356   Green   1   34  4
45555   Green   5   5   2
53443   Brown   3   4   3
```

I have tried this:

```
df.set_index(inplace=True)
df.sort_values(['ID', 'A', 'C'], ascending=['True','False','True'])
```

This didn't work as "ID" as a column was not recognized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you want

```
df.reset_index().sort_values(
    ['ID', 'A', 'C'],
    ascending=['True','False','True']
).set_index(['ID', 'Colour'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can call `sort_values()` to sort columns `A` and `C` and then call `sort_index()` to sort index `ID`:

```
(df.sort_values(['A', 'C'], ascending=[False, True])
   .sort_index(level=0, sort_remaining=False, kind='mergesort'))
```

[image]

Comment: I find this super dangerous: by the documentation mergesort is the only stable algorithm. By default it's quicksort, so it's error prone.

Comment: Thanks so much guys. Great solutions. Problem solved.