# Rearranging the rows in a pandas dataframe of monthly stock returns data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[Pandas Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWbC0.png)

I would like to rearrange the rows here in this dataframe, shown below.
The date is a date time index.

```
  date     ticker     return
20050228     RIY        xxxx
20050228      A         xxxx
20050228     AAN        xxxx
20050228     AAP        xxxx
20050228     AAPL       xxxx
  ....       ...        ...
20050331     RIY        xxxx
20050331      A         xxxx
20050331     AAN        xxxx
20050331     AAP        xxxx
  ....       ...        ...
20171231     RIY        xxxx
20171231      A         xxxx
20171231     AAN        xxxx
20171231     AAP        xxxx
```

The above is a panda dataframe of monthly returns of stocks.
But I would like to get an output that looks like below:

```
   date     ticker     return
20050228     RIY        xxxx
20050331     RIY        xxxx
20050430     RIY        xxxx
  ....       ...         ...
20171231     RIY        xxxx
20050228      A         xxxx
20050331      A         xxxx
20050430      A         xxxx
  ....       ...         ...
20171231      A         xxxx
  ....       ...         ...
```

How can I write the codes to get the above output?

Comment: Can you please explain your logic? How do you go from input to output?

Comment: I currently have the dataframe on the very top. I want to change that dataframe into the bottom dataframe. I'm asking how the codes should be to go from the top to the bottom dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.reset_index().sort_values(['date', 'ticker'],ascending=['True','False']).set_index('date')
```

It seems like you want to sort your index and ticker column. Try the above code, which was repurposed from another Stack question: "[Sorting a table values based on index and non-indexed columns using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853786/sorting-a-table-values-based-on-index-and-non-indexed-columns-using-python)".

Comment: I tried the above codes. It doesn't output the result that I want. I'm not trying to sort here. As explained above in the second dataframe, I need each ticker to go through all the months and then a new ticker will go through all the months and so on. You will understand better if you look carefully what put on top, that is the second dataframe I want to get as the output.